# How to connect to socket.io from Vue.js component?

Tags: node.js, sockets, express, vue.js, websocket

I'm using the Vue-cli webpack template to generate my project about a chatroom with socket.io.

I have tested it with a simple instance when I click the button, the client-side will emit the params to the server-side. But the server-side haven't got anything when I clicked the button.

Could anyone tell me what's the matter with my coding? How can I do to solve that?

Thank you very much!

Here is the client-side

```
<template>
 <div id="app">
 <input type='button' value='button' @click='clickButton()'>
</div>
</template>

<script>
  import Vue from 'vue'
  import VueSocketio from 'vue-socket.io';
  Vue.use(VueSocketio, 'http://localhost:8070/');

  export default {
    name: 'app',
    data() {
      return {
      msg: 'Welcome to Your Vue.js App'
    }
  },
  sockets: {
    connect: function() {
     console.log('socket connected')
  },
  customEmit: function(val) {
     console.log('this method was fired by the socket server. eg: 
     io.emit("customEmit", data)')
    }
  },
  methods: {
     clickButton: function(val) {
     // $socket is socket.io-client instance
     this.$socket.emit('a', 12, 5);
  }
  }
  }
  </script>
```

Here is the server

```
const app = require('express')();
const server = require('http').createServer(app);
const io = require('socket.io');

server.listen(8070);

const ws = io.listen(server);

ws.on('connection',(sock)=>{
  sock.on('a',(num1,num2)=>{
    console.log(`${num1},${num2}`)
  })
})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
  import VueSocketio from 'vue-socket.io';
  Vue.use(VueSocketio, 'http://localhost:8070/');
```

This should be done only once before creating Vue instance. Not in component.

Since you're using Vue-cli webpack, it should be done in `main.js` before `new Vue({})`

Comment: @Sylvia only the `import` and `Vue.use`. after that you can just use `this.$socket` in any component

Comment: Sorry, I am tried to write 'import' and 'Vue.use' in main.js and wrote sendMsg(){this.$socket.emit('a',12,5)} in App.vue, but it still console.log nothing...@Jacob Goh

Comment: @Sylvia i am not sure what's the exact code like on ur side. I tested out your code. it works. it's in https://github.com/jacobgoh101/SO-50148977-client. See https://github.com/jacobgoh101/SO-50148977-client/blob/master/src/components/HelloWorld.vue and

https://github.com/jacobgoh101/SO-50148977-client/blob/master/src/main.js . I am able to get `12,5` in server console using ur exact server code.

Comment: I can't thank you enough @JacobGoh for taking the time to set this up. I was stuck on this for a while before I used your repo example.

Answer (score 0):

```
import socketio from 'socket.io-client'
import VueSocketIO from 'vue-socket.io'
export const SocketInstance = socketio('http://localhost:8081');
 Vue.use(VueSocketIO, SocketInstance)
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing information on how and why it solves the problem improves its long-term value.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide further explanation. Code-only answers can become invalid if the API changes.

Answer (score 0):

After importing the `vue-socket.io` package in main.js you may have to instantiate it as a new class

```
import io from 'socket.io-client'
import VueSocketIO from 'vue-socket.io'
Vue.use(new VueSocketIO({ 
  connection: io('localhost') 
}))
```

per the docs https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-socket.io

Comment: It is initiating the connection on page reload only. If you navigate from one component to another it is not initiating the connection.